# linux redirector to log filename with $date variable

Tags: shell, redirect

I have a script with a line:

```
ruby /root/backup_scripts/new_scripts/aapxen01.rb>>/volumes/backups/aapxen01/$date.log  2>&1
```

This produces a log file named ".log", obviously not what I'm looking for. How do I do it to produce the current date as the filename?

Comment: Can anyone explain why when I use %T or %R the file name ends up something weird like 0XAFKQ~8.log?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace $date with:

```
`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
```

Comment: +%Y-%m-%d can be shortened to +%F. See "man date": http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date

Comment: Can anyone explain why when I use %T or %R the file name ends up something weird like 0XAFKQ~8.log?

Comment: Because %T (and similar %R) makes things like `11:22:33` which contains `:` characters. `:` cannot be in file names - take a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename, in Reserved characters part.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid backquotes and use this instead: `$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')` http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Can anyone explain why when I use %T or %R the file name ends up something weird like 0XAFKQ~8.log?